# Jmockit code coverage gradle

Tags: gradle, jmockit

I am trying to execute jmockit code coverage tool from gradle script like this:
`task jmockit(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "mockit.coverage.CodeCoverage"
    classpath configurations.jmockit
    args("-Djmockit-coverage-output=html," +
            "-Djmockit-coverage-outputDir=${project.projectDir}/coverage-report," +
            "-Djmockit-coverage-srcDirs=${project.projectDir}/src," +
            "-Djmockit-coverage-classes=com.example.*," +
            "coverage-metrics=all")
}`

But I have this exeption:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No input "coverage.ser" files found
    at mockit.coverage.DataFileMerging.merge(DataFileMerging.java:57)
    at mockit.coverage.OutputFileGenerator.generateAggregateReportFromInputFiles(OutputFileGenerator.java:122)
    at mockit.coverage.CodeCoverage.main(CodeCoverage.java:39)
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Where are your `coverage.ser` files located?

Comment: I haven't this file.

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't do it this way (ie, using `mockit.coverage.CodeCoverage#main(String[])`, unless you want to generate an HTML report from two or more coverage.ser files. JMockit automatically generates the HTML report at the end of the current test run. The [documentation](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html) should help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rogério. I rewrited my souce code like this:     `test {
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.jmockit.asPath}=coverage " +
                  "-Djmockit-coverage-output:html " +
               "-Djmockit-coverage-outputDir: ${project.projectDir}/coverage-report " +
            "-Djmockit-coverage-srcDirs: ${project.projectDir}/src/ " +
            "-Djmockit-coverage-classes: com.example.StringUtils " +
            "-Djmockit-coverage-metrics:all "
}`             But when I run task-test, there is no coverage report.